# Custom Regular Expression Validation in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am on my way to implement a custom regular expression validator for one of my MVC3 project.

I have been able to perform validation correctly using the custom atrribute.

The view model property decorated with the below custom attribute

[RegularExpressionIF("DependantProperty","TargetValue","Pattern","ErrorMessage")]

But my requirement is , I need to match property1 values with a certain regular expressions based on Property2 value. For ex. Property 2 is a dropdown and has values 1,2,3 . If the user selects 1, the regular expresion pattern will be {REGX1}, for 2 {REGX2} like that.

I tried to modify the Attribute by passing the variables which contain these values.  But on build .Net insists that it should be a "constant" to be passed. I am able to hard code the value in the attribute, but in no way I can pass a parameter like below

[RegularExpressionIF("DependantProperty","TargetValue",patternDictionary,"ErrorMessage")]

If anyone could help me out in this that would be great..

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use reflection to get the value of the property at runtime.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
    object value, 
    ValidationContext context)
{
    // DependantProperty is the string name of the dependant property
    PropertyInfo property = context.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.DependantProperty);
    object dependant = property.GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);

    // do something with dependant
}
```